# Symfony $id must be a string Exception

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, swiftmailer

Hi Ive recently installed Symfony and when running my url I get this error, I tried checking online but for the life of me I cant get a solution to why this is happening. PLEASE HELP :(

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message '$id must be a string, or an Alias object.' in D:\PersonalProject\auctionbackend\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php:662 Stack trace: #0 D:\PersonalProject\auctionbackend\vendor\symfony\swiftmailer-bundle\DependencyInjection\SwiftmailerExtension.php(223): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->setAlias('swiftmailer.mai...', 21) #1 D:\PersonalProject\auctionbackend\vendor\symfony\swiftmailer-bundle\DependencyInjection\SwiftmailerExtension.php(92): Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DependencyInjection\SwiftmailerExtension->configureMailerSpool('default', Array, Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder), 21, true) #2 D:\PersonalProject\auctionbackend\vendor\symfony\swiftmailer-bundle\DependencyInjection\SwiftmailerExtension.php(53): Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DependencyInjection\SwiftmailerExtension->configureMailer in D:\PersonalProject\auctionbackend\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php on line 662

**CONFIG**

```
 swiftmailer:
    transport:  "%mailer_transport%"
    host:       "%mailer_host%"
    port:       "993"
    username:   "%mailer_user%"
    password:   "%mailer_password%"
    port:       "%mailer_port%"
    encryption: "ssl"
    password:   "%mailer_password%"
    spool:      { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: TopNode\SupportBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address:      support@top-node.com
        sender_name:  Support

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
            blameable: true
            sluggable: true

knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: SupportBundle:Default:pagination.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template
services:
    twig.extension.text:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
    salavert.twig.time_ago:
        class: Salavert\Twig\Extension\TimeAgoExtension
        arguments: [@translator]
        tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

**UPDATE**

It seems to fail on the InstallAssets cmd in the script below

**Composer file**

```
 "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
```

**Detailed Error**

```
in ContainerBuilder.php line 662
at ContainerBuilder->setAlias('swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real', '25') in SwiftmailerExtension.php line 223
at SwiftmailerExtension->configureMailerSpool('default', array('transport' => '25', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '993', 'username' => 'test@test.com', 'password' => '2382752398', 'encryption' => 'ssl', 'spool' => array('type' => 'memory', 'path' => '%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool', 'id' => null), 'timeout' => '30', 'source_ip' => null, 'auth_mode' => null, 'logging' => true, 'delivery_whitelist' => array()), object(ContainerBuilder), '25', true) in SwiftmailerExtension.php line 92
at SwiftmailerExtension->configureMailer('default', array('transport' => '25', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '993', 'username' => 'test@test', 'password' => '852359', 'encryption' => 'ssl', 'spool' => array('type' => 'memory', 'path' => '%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool', 'id' => null), 'timeout' => '30', 'source_ip' => null, 'auth_mode' => null, 'logging' => true, 'delivery_whitelist' => array()), object(ContainerBuilder), true) in SwiftmailerExtension.php line 53
at SwiftmailerExtension->load(array(array('transport' => '25', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '993', 'username' => 'test@test.com', 'password' => '8235259', 'encryption' => 'ssl', 'spool' => array('type' => 'memory'))), object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 59
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 104
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 598
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2754
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in AppKernel.php line 43
at AppKernel->initializeContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2529
at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2560
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 29
```

Comment: Add `swiftmailer` config to question

Comment: Sorry for the noob question where can I find this ?

Comment: In the file `app/config/config.yml` everything below the `swiftmailer` key.

Comment: I've attached the config above

Comment: Looks like you are trying to upgrade a project to S3.3?  The autowire is messing you up.  I suppose you could try setting autowire: false in app/config/services.yml though that is just a shot in the dark.  I suspect at least one of your dependencies did not get updated.  Might start with a clean S33 project then add one dependency at a time.

Comment: I tried that but still getting the same error :( feeling hopeless not sure why this is not working on a fresh install

Comment: It looks like its falling over at the InstallAssets command but doesnt make sense to me why as it should be installed